# MySQL.Избавление от дупликатов

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть поле производитель и деталь, которую он производит . Мне нужно получить пары таких деталей, которые одновременно принадлежат одному производителю.

Пример таблицы:

| Производитель | Деталь |
| --- | --- |
| П1 | 1 |
| П1 | 2 |
| П2 | 2 |
| П2 | 5 |
| П3 | 3 |
| П3 | 2 |
| П3 | 4 |

В результате мне нужно получить пары [1,2],[2,5],[3,2],[3,4],[2,4].

Сам я написал такой запрос:

```
select distinct concat (B.`Д`,',',A.`Д`) 
from `mydb`.`result` as B  
join ( select A.`Д`,A.`П` 
       from `mydb`.`result` as A) as A using(`П`) 
where A.`Д`!=B.`Д` 
  and A.`П`=B.`П`;
```

Однако у меня тогда появляется проблема, что может отобразиться такой ответ как [2,1],[1,2]. Хотя они являются одной и той же парой . Можно ли это как-то исправить и как или же проблема кроется в самом запросе? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: *[2,1],[1,2]. Хотя они являются одной и той же парой .* Это ты можешь их считать "одной парой". А с точки зрения СУБД это две различающиеся записи. Всё, точка.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.detail, t2.detail
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (vendor)
WHERE t1.detail < t2.detail
```